# Embed youtube video in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, video, youtube, embed

I'm trying to embed video in pages. I tried two different ways but no luck

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @video.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Url:</b>
  <%= @video.url %>
</p>

<p>
    <% #video_tag( @video.url , :size => "560x315", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true ) %>
    <%= youtube_video @video.url%>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_video_path(@video) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', videos_path %>
```

The video does not show neither does the links below it.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you

this is the debug result

> ActionView::MissingTemplate in Videos#show
>
> Showing
>   /Users/atbyrd/Documents/sites/city/app/views/videos/show.html.erb
>   where line #15 raised:
>
> Missing partial shared/video with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/Users/atbyrd/Documents/sites/city/app/views"   *
>   "/Users/atbyrd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.5.1/app/views"
>
> Extracted source (around line #15):
>
> 12:  13:
>
> 14:  <% #video_tag( @video.url , :size => "560x315",
>   :controls => true, :autobuffer => true ) %> 15:   <%= youtube_video
>   @video.url%> 16:
>
> 17:  18: <%= link_to 'Edit',
>   edit_video_path(@video) %> |
>
> Rails.root: /Users/atbyrd/Documents/sites/city Application Trace |
>   Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/helpers/application_helper.rb:4:in `youtube_video'
>   app/views/videos/show.html.erb:15:in`
>   _app_views_videos_show_html_erb__1532956397246631491_70281299458880'
>   app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:18:in `show'

Comment: Could you provide your `@video.url` and rendered HTML? I think the first way should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have forgotten to close a bracket

```
<%= video_tag( @video.url %>
```

should be

```
<%= video_tag( @video.url ) %>
```

UPDATE:

**Try using [video_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_path) instead of video_tag.**

2nd UPDATE:

here's how I do this myself on my own site:

1 - create a partial called _video.html.erb (I actually use haml, but erb will do if you prefer it) and put it in a folder like views/shared or something ad put the following code in it:

```
<iframe width="490" height="275" src="<%= url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

2 add the following method to application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # this method will embed the code from the partial
  def youtube_video(url)
    render :partial => 'shared/video', :locals => { :url => url }
  end 
end
```

3 - now just call this in your views with:

```
<%= youtube_video @video.url %>
```

This works ok for me

Comment: ok i see this is actually working but the video is not playing back a can right click on it and select play videos. It then sends me to the youtube page

Comment: updated source and resulting html. I can see it buffer at first but never get it to play

Comment: Ah, can we see the code from your video_tag helper method too please? Also, I take it video.url is a correctly formatted URL? Like http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyzzz?

Comment: <video width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0ch5iwiHAU0" controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" tabindex="0">
</video>

Comment: PS _ updated my answer, the docs for the [video_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag) method state: _The sources can be full paths or files that exists in your public videos directory._ I'm thinking video_path should fix this :) hopefully

Comment: Video path just results with "/videos/2"

Answer (score 1):

I got it, you forgot to use erb syntax. Try:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src= "<%= #{@video.url} %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Brandon is right. This time you missed the `)` after `video_tag( @video.url`

Answer (score 1):

@miaout17 is right, you can't use string interpolation in HTML, so you have to wrap it in Erb (e.g. <%= %>).

Also you're missing an ending ')' in your links below which is probably why they aren't working.