# Embedding Youtube Videos in Phoenix EEX templates

Tags: iframe, youtube, elixir, phoenix-framework

I wrote the following code to display projects:

```
<%= for project <- @projects do %>
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="panel panel-default"  style="min-height: 1200px; margin-bottom:50px;height:auto;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <img src="<%= Microflow.Avatar.url({project.picture, project}, :original) %>" alt="" width="330px" height="240px"/>

      </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 350px">
      <h2 style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;"><%= project.name %></h2>
      <h3 style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;"><%= raw(project.description) %></h3>
      <h2 style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">

      </h2>
      <h2 style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;"><%= project.raise_amount %> USD</h2>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src= "<%=project.video_url%>"</iframe>  
<%= link "Delete Project", to: project_path(@conn, :delete, project), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
<%= link "Start Your Own Project", to: project_path(@conn, :new), method: :new, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs" %>
          </div>
           </div>
             </div>
<% end %>
```

It all works fine, apart from this line:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src= "<%=project.video_url%>"</iframe>
```

Which displays:

```
"No route found for GET /Video%20Goes%20Here (MyApp.Router)"
```

Do I need to fix my routes or define a function?... The following Ruby guide may still work in Phoenix/Elixir, with some adjustments:

[How to add youtube frame to ERB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979938/how-to-add-youtube-frame-to-erb-file)
[Embed youtube video in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272026/embed-youtube-video-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with this:

```
<% video_string = to_string(project.video_url) %>
 <% video = String.slice(video_string,32,String.length(video_string)) %>
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" position= "absolute"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=video%>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Maybe not best practice, but it's a workaround for now.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you might be using a relative path for the video URL. This means that it will be served relative to your current URL.

For example, if you are on `http://example.com/projects/1` and the `project.video_url` is `/some_video_url` then the iframe will use`http://example.com/some_video_url.

If you are trying to embed a YouTube video and only have the id, then you will need to prepend https://www.youtube.com/embed/ which means the iframe will use https://www.youtube.com/embed/some_video_id:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=project.video_url%>"</iframe>
```

It might also be worth moving this into a function so that if YouTube update their embed URL you only need to make the changes in one place.

Comment: I would definitely wrap that call inside of a function for exactly the reason you mention @Gazler. Calling a function is a great way to implement DRY.

Comment: Thanks Gazler, that has helped somewhat. My original code works OK with an absolute path to a specific video, but when I call youtube urls saved in the database they don't display. Using the line of code you wrote will link me to a blank youtube video. I think I will use the examples in Chris Mccord's Phoenix book instead.